# You are looking well VS You are looking good

Tags: word-choice

My first concern: well or good?
My second concern: Why don't they write it in simple present? You look well !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Good** is always an *adjective* and never an adverb. It never modifies a verb but it generally follows a linking verb serving a subject-modifier. On the other hand, **well** can be an *adjective or adverb* depending on context.

> You are looking good - you look attractive. 
>   You are looking well - your health seems well; it seems you are in the pink of health.

You can use both present continuous and simple present. That's because it's happening right in front of you! (You look good/you look well).

Comment: Maulik is absolutely right. I just want to add that you  can use both the present simple/ and present continuous.

Comment: @Maulik V - Thanks a million, and why do they write it in present continious form ?

Comment: Because we use the present continuous when we're talking about actions that are taking place now, at the moment of speaking. If for example, I see in the street this very moment, I will say" Hey, you are looking good", since you're looking good to me right now, the moment we are speaking. (note: When "look" means 'appears", then we can use it in the present continuous.

Comment: On the other hand an unchanged state using "look" can only be used in present simple. Consider "He looks like his father".

Comment: But: "He's looking more like his father every day" is OK because it describes a changing state.

Comment: Good is used as an adverb in cases like, "I slept good." That's a common linguistically descriptive (not prescriptive) usage.

Answer (score 3):

You can say any of them.  Note statements like "You look well" is part of a more formal English dialect. It's use or non-use can signify a person as belonging to a particular social class.

- **You're looking good.**

  - A statement about overall good looks, possibly including health.
  - Currently; possibly as opposed to previously; also, if you haven't seen the person in a long time.
- **You look good.**

  - A more simple compliment.
  - Not related to any prior view of how they looked nor related to the passage of time.
- **You're looking well.**

  - This is a statement specifically about health.
  - Currently; possibly as opposed to previously; also, if you haven't seen the person in a long time.
- **You look well.**

  - A more simple compliment about health.
  - Not related to any prior view of how they looked nor related to the passage of time.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolinguistics.